# javascript regex to get characters between the ":"'s from "Retail Sales of Electricity : Colorado : Commercial : Annual"

Tags: javascript, regex

Ideally, I'd like to skip the spaces on either side.

I've gotten as far as `(: \S*)`, which obviously isn't really what I want.

getting the text between as groups would be great.

Comment: Split on ":" and trim.

Comment: @DaveNewton I need it to be a regex, but that would work.

Comment: `Retail Sales of Electricity : Colorado : Commercial : Annual".split(/\s*:\s*/g);` will give
`["Retail Sales of Electricity", "Colorado", "Commercial", "Annual"]`

Comment: Why do you need it to be a regex?

Comment: @DaveNewton there are some additional parameters involved in my problem that I didn't include in the question. I only asked what needed to be answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var str = "Retail Sales of Electricity : Colorado : Commercial : Annual";
str.match(/\b[^:]+\b/g);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try with:

```
var input  = "Retail Sales of Electricity : Colorado : Commercial : Annual";

var output = input.split(':').map(function(s){ return s.trim(); });
```